# How to generate a string primary key on database and define it with JPA Annotations

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to have an entity with a string pk, which is generated by database with a static prefix and a sequence. I get this error when I try to insert a new row via my spring application. Can someone help me?

My Error:

```
"Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String"
```

My Table sql:

```
CREATE sequence octo_reference_code;

SELECT setval('octo_reference_code', 1010);

create table user_references
(
code text not null default 'octo' || nextval('octo_reference_code')
    constraint user_references_pk
        primary key,
user_id uuid
    constraint user_references_users_id_fk
        references users,
create_date timestamptz default now()
);
```

My entity class pk definition:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "code", columnDefinition = "text", nullable = false, updatable = false)
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the sequence to a TEXT.  Append `::TEXT` to the end of the `nextval()` call:

`code text not null default 'octo' || nextval('octo_reference_code')::TEXT`

Answer (score 0):

You can define that your id uses the sequence that you defined in your database, for this you can add the following:

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "octo_reference_code", sequenceName = "octo_reference_code", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "octo_reference_code")
    @Column(name = "code")
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it worked.But I want it to be handled by db, not app.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to write a custom class String identifier generator **StringSequenceIdentifier** which contain the **static prefix** as a String.  [Click here for more detail](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-write-a-custom-sequence-based-string-id-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/2306/2)

**Custom String Sequential identifier generator**

```
public class StringSequenceIdentifier implements 
        IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

    public static final String SEQUENCE_PREFIX = "sequence_prefix";

    private String sequencePrefix;

    private String sequenceCallSyntax;

    @Override
    public void configure(
            Type type,
            Properties params,
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
        throws MappingException {

        final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment = serviceRegistry.getService(
                JdbcEnvironment.class
        );

        final Dialect dialect = jdbcEnvironment.getDialect();

        final ConfigurationService configurationService = serviceRegistry.getService(
                ConfigurationService.class
        );

        String globalEntityIdentifierPrefix = configurationService.getSetting(
            "entity.identifier.prefix",
            String.class,
            "SEQ_"
        );

        sequencePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(
            SEQUENCE_PREFIX,
            params,
            globalEntityIdentifierPrefix
        );

        final String sequencePerEntitySuffix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(
            SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY_SUFFIX,
            params,
            SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_SUFFIX
        );

        boolean preferSequencePerEntity = ConfigurationHelper.getBoolean(
            SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY,
            params,
            false
        );

        final String defaultSequenceName = preferSequencePerEntity
                ? params.getProperty(JPA_ENTITY_NAME) + sequencePerEntitySuffix
                : SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_NAME;

        sequenceCallSyntax = dialect.getSequenceNextValString(
            ConfigurationHelper.getString(
                SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM,
                params,
                defaultSequenceName
            )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Identifiable) {
            Identifiable identifiable = (Identifiable) obj;
            Serializable id = identifiable.getId();

            if (id != null) {
                return id;
            }
        }

        long seqValue = ((Number)
                Session.class.cast(session)
                .createNativeQuery(sequenceCallSyntax)
                .uniqueResult()
        ).longValue();

        return sequencePrefix + String.format("%011d%s", 0 ,seqValue);
    }
}
```

**And mapping it into the entity class for the Id field**

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "assigned-sequence",
    strategy = "com.custom.identifier.StringSequenceIdentifier",
    parameters = {
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "sequence_name", value = "hibernate_sequence"),
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "sequence_prefix", value = "ABC_"),
    }
)
@GeneratedValue(
    generator = "assigned-sequence",
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private String code;
```